# Export user from multiple groups

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Good Morning Guys,

I write this script to export multiple users in multiple groups in a CSV file.

In addition to not exporting anything, I cannot insert a column in the CSV where the user's appatenency group is specified. Just the one with the name "vpn-*", like vpn-users

Powershell Version 4.0

```
$Data = $UserData = @()
$GroupName = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "VPN-*"} -Properties Name | Select-Object Name
Foreach ($group in $GroupName)
{
$UserData = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity {$group}
Where objectClass -eq 'user' | 
Get-ADUser -Properties Name, UserPrincipalName, description, Enabled |
Select-Object Name, UserPrincipalName, description, Enabled 
}
$UserData  | export-csv "c:\members2.csv"
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you actually using?

Comment: `Select-Object Name` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` on the first line. Also `-Filter` should be a syring, not a scriptblock : 
`"name -like 'VPN-*'"`

Comment: @Theo Powershell Version 4.0

Comment: Then, would you please remove the tags for versions 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @Theo Done, but i have the same problem. I edit the code as you recommended, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: You don't need a script block for `-Identity` either. Remove the `{}` to have `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group`

Comment: Thanks, but i not have the correct column in csv with only this data -> Name, UserPrincipalName, description, Enabled + Group Name (Example vpn-users)

Comment: And add switch `-NoTypeInformation` to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet

Comment: I had to insert ```$UserData | export-csv "C:\OPTIONS\VPN-GROUPS.csv" -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation``` inside ```Foreach``` otherwise I was only getting the first line as output. Within the csv, can I add the group name, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of issues with the posted code. Some are mere preferences, but others look like they would affect the outcome.

`-Properties Name` isn't needed in the initial `Get-ADGroup` command. The Name property is returned by default.

Respectful to @Theo's comment re: `-ExpandProperty`, however, I prefer not to use that unnecessarily.  You don't even need the first `Select-Object` command, just reference the property and it will unroll and return a string array. Property unrolling is supported as of PowerShell Version 3.

Your argument to the `-Filter` parameter should be a string. I myself have a hard time breaking the habit of wrapping those queries in script blocks `{...}`, however, there are some specifics of the AD cmdlets, and using a string is a best practice.  Basically, the argument takes a string type, if you give it a script block it will convert it to a string and that process may not always work as desired.

It's better to store your AD properties in an array you can cite multiple times.  Normally you would've only needed to add 'Description' but considering you were also using it in a later `Select-Object` command it makes more sense to add all the desired properties to an array.

Personally, I prefer not to use simplified syntax. I don't know what the community's opinion is on that but I rewrote using my preference.

You were also missing  `|`' before the `Where-Object` command.

And, yes you would have to move the `Export-Csv` inside the loop to output data per loop iteration.  Using the `-Append` parameter to avoid overwriting it on every iteration.

Untested Example:

```
$ADProps = 'Name', 'UserPrincipalName', 'description', 'Enabled'

$GroupName = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'VPN-*'" ).Name

Foreach ( $Group in $GroupName )
{
    $UserData = 
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group |
    Where-Object{ $_.objectclass -eq 'user' } | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties $ADProps |
    Select-Object ($ADProps += @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = { $Group }})

    $UserData | export-csv "c:\members2.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. I test your script, and as I also told @Theo, I need to add a column that tells me the name of the group it belongs to. In your script, but I get this error  ```The term 'objectClass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet```

Comment: That was a typo on my part, it's corrected now.  Let me take a look on the extra property.

Comment: I added the I'm not exactly thrilled with the last `Select-Object` command. I've had mixed results trying to combine arrays and the change messes up the strategy with `$ADProps` a little.  Anyway, this should work and we can revise further if needed.

Comment: Thanks @steven for help me